# Space Formatting data to csv

Tags: regex, csv, awk, formatting, pretty-print

For quite some time I have been trying to format space separated data to a CSV structure.

### Initial position

The initial data table is given by:

```
Dr. Arun Raykar MBBS, MS - ENT 9 years experience Ear-Nose-Throat (ENT) Specialist SHAKTHI E.N.T CARE    Malleswaram, Bangalore INR 250 MON-SAT7:00PM-9:00PM Book Appointment   
Dr. Hema Sanath C BHMS, CFN 0 years experience Homeopath Sankirana Homeopathic Clinic    Kalyan Nagar, Bangalore INR 250 MON-SAT10:00AM-2:00PM6:30PM-8:00PM Book Appointment   
Dr. Hema Ahuja BDS,M Phil 33 years experience Dentist V2 E City Family Dental Center     Electronics City, Bangalore INR 200 MON-SUN10:00AM-8:00PM Book Appointment
```

It contains lots of spaces and unnecessary information throughout. The information is present somewhat like this

```
Doctor's name | Degree | Years of experience | Specialization | Hospital name | Address | Fees | Schedule | and an unnecessary book appointment field.
```

I want to convert it to the following format

```
Doctor's name,Specialization,Hospital name,Address,Fees,Schedule
```

So the current data should look like this

```
 Dr. Arun Raykar,Ear-Nose-Throat (ENT) Specialist,SHAKTHI E.N.T CARE,Malleswaram,INR 250,MON-SAT7:00PM-9:00PM
 Dr. Hema Sanath,Homeopath,Sankirana Homeopathic Clinic,Kalyan Nagar,INR 250,MON-SAT10:00AM-2:00PM6:30PM-8:00PM   
 Dr. Hema Ahuja,Dentist,V2 E City Family Dental Center,Electronics City,INR 200,MON-SUN10:00AM-8:00PM
```

Till now I have succeeded in removing the Book Appointment field.

### Problem

However I am facing difficulties in classifying the hospital's name. As the spacing in it varies a lot. Is this problem feasible?

### EDIT

The output of `cat -A file` is the following:

```
 Dr. Arun Raykar MBBS, MS - ENT 9 years experience Ear-Nose-Throat (ENT) Specialist SHAKTHI E.N.T CARE ^I Malleswaram, Bangalore INR 250 MON-SAT7:00PM-9:00PM Book Appointment $
 Dr. Hema Sanath C BHMS, CFN 0 years experience Homeopath Sankirana Homeopathic Clinic ^I Kalyan Nagar, Bangalore INR 250 MON-SAT10:00AM-2:00PM6:30PM-8:00PM Book Appointment $
 Dr. Hema Ahuja BDS,M Phil 33 years experience Dentist V2 E City Family Dental Center ^I Electronics City, Bangalore INR 200 MON-SUN10:00AM-8:00PM Book Appointment
```

Comment: seems there are some `tabs` in your original files, could you please run the command `cat -A file` and update the output to us?

Comment: I have added the output of cat -A in the EDIT section

Comment: Is there any way to have some kind of separation between the Specialization and the Hospital name?

Comment: The horizontal tab character is another common value separator. The comma character is not the only one used for separating values. I'm asking now myself if you have removed by replacing the tab characters by spaces the separator character which would have made it easy to reformat the tab separated CSV file into a comma separated CSV file with the data you want in the order you want.

Comment: A CSV file using tabs as separator can be imported into a blank Microsoft Excel sheet using the [Import Text Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx) of Excel.

Comment: Whatever is generating this file needs to insert the proper separators otherwise there is no way to perfectly solve this problem programatically. If you cannot modify the source of the file, you can use one of the solutions below to get an almost fixed version then have a human manually review it for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to separate the specialization from the hospital name, but with some assumptions, you could perhaps use `perl` to do this:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).+experience\s([^\t]+?)\s+(\b[A-Z0-9]{2}[^\t]+?|(?:(?!\b[A-Z0-9]{2})[^\t])*)\s+\t\s+([^,]+,).+?(INR.+?PM)\s+.*/\1,\2,\3,\4\5/' file
```

Gives:

```
Dr. Arun Raykar,Ear-Nose-Throat (ENT) Specialist,SHAKTHI E.N.T CARE,Malleswaram,INR 250 MON-SAT7:00PM-9:00PM
Dr. Hema Sanath,Homeopath,Sankirana Homeopathic Clinic,Kalyan Nagar,INR 250 MON-SAT10:00AM-2:00PM6:30PM-8:00PM
Dr. Hema Ahuja,Dentist,V2 E City Family Dental Center,Electronics City,INR 200 MON-SUN10:00AM-8:00PM
```

And since it's perl based regex, you can use [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mI6uQ1) to get a glimpse of how it works through the regex debugger. The regex is quite straightforward, but the fact that there are many parts can make it appear daunting.

Warning: The above is able to separate the specialization based on two things:

1. It tries to find the first occurrence of space followed by two uppercase characters or digits and starts matching as the hospital name when it finds it; or
2. If there are no consecutive uppercase characters or digits, it takes only the first word as the specialization and the rest as the hospital name.

I know it might not solve the complete problems as there are always lines that won't fit the above rules, but that can get you started on cleaning these up. If there is anything incorrectly separated (i.e. when the specialization consists of more than 1 word and the hospital name doesn't have two consecutive upper/digit) you will have one word of the specialization correctly placed, and the rest in the hospital name.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, based on your input, there's no way to separate specialisation with hospital name. The other fields can be captured, albeit inelegantly and with gawk (probably >= 4.0, but I think 3.x should work):

```
$ awk -F" \t " -v OFS="," -v S=" " '
{
    sub(/\s+$/, "");
    split($2, Data, /[ ,]{2,}/);
    Address  = Data[1];
    split($2, Data, / +/);
    nData    = length(Data);
    Schedule = Data[nData - 2];
    Fees     = Data[nData - 4] S Data[nData - 3];
    split($1, Data, / +/);
    Name     = Data[1] S Data[2] S Data[3]; # assume all names are Dr. Xxx Xxx only
    match($1, /[0-9]+ years experience /);
    SpecializationHospital = substr($1, RSTART + RLENGTH);
    print Name, SpecializationHospital, Address, Fees, Schedule;
} ' data.txt
Dr. Arun Raykar,Ear-Nose-Throat (ENT) Specialist SHAKTHI E.N.T CARE,Malleswaram,INR 250,MON-SAT7:00PM-9:00PM
Dr. Hema Sanath,Homeopath Sankirana Homeopathic Clinic,Kalyan Nagar,INR 250,MON-SAT10:00AM-2:00PM6:30PM-8:00PM
Dr. Hema Ahuja,Dentist V2 E City Family Dental Center,Electronics City,INR 200,MON-SUN10:00AM-8:00PM
```